# How to "inherit" from a target in ant

Tags: ant

I have an target of the following form

```
<target name="runTool" depends="build">
    <java className="ToolMain" fork="true" clonevm="true" failonerror="true">
    <arg......>
    <jvmarg.....>
    ....
</target>
```

I want to add an additional target for the debug path, which has all other args same as this one but an additional arg to listen on the debug port.

```
<target name="runTool-debug" depends="build">
...same program ....
......and same args......
<jvmarg value="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=5005,server=y,suspend=n"/>
</target>
```

What is the best way to achieve this without duplicating the entire target?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a property named `debug.flag` for instance and use it to add the additional arguments when it is set to `true`:

```
<target name="runTool" depends="build">
    <condition property="debug.jvmargs"
       value="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=5005,server=y,suspend=n"
       else="">
          <equals arg1="${debug.flag}" arg2="true" />
    </condition>
    <java className="ToolMain" fork="true" clonevm="true" failonerror="true">
       <arg......>
       <jvmarg.....>
       <jvmarg value="${debug.jvmargs}" />
       ....
</target>
```

In the `condition` task, when `debug.flag` is true, `debug.jvmargs` is set to `-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=5005,server=y,suspend=n`, else it is empty.

To set the property to `true`, you can run `ant -Ddebug.flag=true ...`.